# Get size of directory (including all its content) irrespective of disk usage

Tags: disk-usage, file-copy, size

**General question**

Assuming two directories with identical content are stored on different devices. Is there a way to calculate the size of the directories and always get the exact same number for both?
In other words, is there such a thing as a "real size" of a directory irrespective of where it is stored?

**Practical example**

I transferred directories between two storage devices using `rsync -ahP /dir1/ /dir2/`. 
After the transfer finished without errors, I checked the sizes of the directories on each device using `du -s --apparent-size`. For some directories I got the exact same number on both devices, but not for all of them.

**Specific questions**

Is it possible that `rsync` with the chosen options didn't produce an exact copy of the directory? If yes, would there be a way to get an exact copy?

Does the used `du` command not give the "real size" of the directory irrespective of the storage device. If yes, would there be a way to calculate such a size?

Comment: Please define "real size" of a directory. Do you mean the size of the metadata (unit? Perhaps number of entries?), or the sum of the file sizes (not on disk) or what?  The size on disk will always depend on your file system and its parameters like inode/cluster size.

Comment: With "real size" I mean a value that will always be the same, irrespective of the size on disk.

Comment: Yes, but please define the size of the following data to see how you calculate it: "brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Aug 29 09:28 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Aug 29 09:28 /dev/sda1" - how many bytes does this metadata have? (More metadata exists but is not shown.)

Comment: Not sure if I understood your comment. Are you saying that an objective size of a file does not exist, as the metadata will always differ on different disks?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For example: How many bytes do you use to save a date+time? It depends on the representation (e.g. unsigned long integer as number of seconds since 01.01.1970, or 1 byte each for day, month, hour, second etc.).  So, its very difficult indeed to define a definitive size.  You can perhaps compare the metadata but not its size.

Comment: Would it be possible then to calculate the size of all metadata and subtract it from the total size of the directory to get an objective size?

Comment: Again, The metadata is stored on disk. You read it with functions that modify the way the data is stored (see e.g. http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html ). The size you have is the size of that data structure times the number of directory entries.  As I said, it is not the size on disk because `getdents64` etc. modify the representation since they can read from different file systems that use different storage systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `du`, even GNU's one with its `--apparent-size` option will include the apparent size (as reported by `lstat()`) of all types of files, including *regular files*, *devices*, *symlinks*, *fifos*, *directories*. GNU `du` like many other implementations will try to not count the same file several times (like when there are several hard links to the same file).

Here, since you're not passing the `-H` option to `rsync`, hard links won't be preserved so that exclusion of duplicates in `du`'s account would cause a discrepancy if there were hard links in the source.

The apparent size of a file of type *directory* does represent the real size of its *data*: a list of file names alongside information on where to find them, but the format and size of that list depends on the type of file system, how it was configured, and how the directory was populated.

For device files, fifos, sockets for which `rsync` doesn't transfer any data, some systems (like Linux) always return 0 as the apparent size, some will return the amount of data that could be read from them (for block device files for instance, it could be the size of the corresponding storage).

So here, probably the best you can do is compute the sum of the apparent size of *regular* and *symlink* files which are the ones consistent from one system to another¹.

You could do that with GNU `find` with:

```
find . -type f,l -printf '%s\n' | awk '{s+=$0}; END{print s}'
```

If you find the same number on the source and destination that would be an indication that `rsync` may have managed to transfer all the *data* (the contents of regular files, and symlinks (their target path)). It may not have managed to transfer all metadata like extended attributes, ACLs (both of which you're not preserving anyway since you didn't pass the `-X` and `-A` options), file names, empty files...

As a consistent representation of the amount of directories data (assuming no encoding issue¹), you could use `find . | wc -c` (the sum of all file paths length + 1).

You could also re-run the same `rsync` command with `-n` (dry-run) and `-v` (verbose) to check if things are missing, maybe adding a `--delete` to also check for files that are on the destination and not the source.

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, symlink sizes could vary if there were some transformations operated on file names like in some cases of character encoding transformations for non-ASCII characters especially if there are non-Unix or macOS file systems involved</sup>

Comment: and if the OP wanted to ignore duplicate inodes like `du` does, they could print the inode number as well as the size in the -printf format string: `find . -type f,l -printf '%i %s\n' | awk '!seen[$1]++ { s+=$2 } ; END {print s}'`

Comment: @cas of course you need the device number %D in there as well as inode numbers are only unique within the device (traditionally the top level directory in each device has inode number 2).

Comment: @icarus true, i didn't think about the case of crossing filesystems.

Comment: @Cas, yes though you'd only want to do it to test the effectiveness of `rsync`'s `-H` option (which the OP is not using). I only brought that up as a behaviour of `du` that is **not** wanted here. I've made it more explicit now.

Comment: The `find` command line to calculate the sum of the apparent size of regular files (I exclude symlink files for my purpose) is basically what I was looking for (now that I know that the "real size" I was asking about does not exist).

Answer (score 3):

Rsync and other tools will not copy directories exactly. They may or may not copy sparse files exactly. This is **not** something to be concerned about in general.

Consider the following bash example.

```
 mkdir -p /tmp/demo/a
 cd /tmp/demo/a
 touch {1..10000}
 ls -ld
```

this creates 10,000 files and lists the size of the directory holding them. On my system I get a directory of size 155648 bytes. Now remove 9,000 of them and check the size again.

```
 rm ????
 ls -ld
```

The size of the directory for me is unchanged at 155648 bytes. Now make a copy, here I am using `cp` but it could be `rsync` or `cpio` or anything else that copies files

```
 cd ..
 cp -r a b
 ls -l
```

For me the `b` directory is only 20,480 bytes, i.e. 135,168 smaller. This is because the `a` directory has space in it for the entry for the file 3141 which was deleted, but `b` doesn't have this space allocated.

Comment: That's a nice example, answering some of my questions. I accepted the other answer as it explains other aspects of my questions too.